# Expected type: java.util.List, actual value: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet

Tags: gwt, one-to-many

I do have a mapping file for F which is linked to others through many-to-one relations.
I had to add a relation one-to-many from F to HF

Following have been added to F mapping file

```
                    <set name="hf" fetch="join"  inverse="false" lazy="true" order-by="DATECRE">
                    <key>
                    <column name="METIER" />
                    <column name="SITEGEO" />
                    <column name="CPTDOSSIER" />
                    <column name="NUMLIGNE" />
                    </key>
                    <one-to-many class="HF" />
                    </set>
```

When using it, i have the following errors. 
I thought it could be inverse property to be changed but F should be the relationship owner, so i set it to false.

May someone guide me ?

```
ERROR 06/02/2014 16:42:30 [BasicPropertyAccessor.java.set(117)] HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: org.nit.persistance.entites.base.BF, setter method of property: hf
ERROR 06/02/2014 16:42:30 [BasicPropertyAccessor.java.set(118)] HHH000091: Expected type: java.util.List, actual value: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet
INFO  06/02/2014 16:42:30 [DefaultLoadEventListener.java.onLoad(159)] HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of org.nit.persistance.entites.base.BF.hf
```

In my FProxy, i have added the following line.
I have no need of setting HF at all.

```
List<HFProxy> getHf();
```

In F class, following was added

```
private List<HF> hf;

public List<HF> getHf() {
    return hf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by

A. Creating a getter only in the proxy part.

`List<HistoFichesProxy> getHistofiches();`

B. Creating a getter and setter in the entity F.

C. Modifying F hbm file as :

```
                <bag name="hf" fetch="join"  inverse="false" lazy="true" order-by="DATECRE">
                <key>
                <column name="METIER" />
                <column name="SITEGEO" />
                <column name="CPTDOSSIER" />
                <column name="NUMLIGNE" />
                </key>
                <one-to-many class="HF" />
                </bag>
```